# Keep default width on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, html-email, mjml

i am trying to keep the original default width for `mj-body` on mobile view as well, because i calculate my image's width based on screen width and its width in percentage value so i need the screen width to be persistent, now here's  the code that i use https://mjml.io/try-it-live/s743_l6g7

now as i see problem lies in here

[image]

mjml automatically adds fits columns to the screen which messes up my desired result on mobile, i want to override this and always have 600px screen width even on devices smaller than 480px screen size and have zoomed out view as it would have been normally

Comment: Please put code into your question, not an image. And make sure you show the relevant HTML as well as CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: the image is tranformed version of code, and i believe it would be easier to test and view in the playground than to copy the code just to paste it in the editor again

Comment: Hi, it's possible you have missed one of the points of StackOverflow - while we are here to help you individually if we can, the idea is that a repository of question/answers is built up for future readers. If you do not put your code into the question then the danger (and it's a very likely to happen thing) is that the offsite site gets taken down at some point and the Q/A becomes useless. I'll follow your question so if you do put the code into the question as asked then I'll willingly have a look.